# I want te measure distance from start position while driving

Tags: android, kotlin

I am building an Android application to measure 1km from a start position while driving.

i tried this : https://github.com/quentin7b/android-location-tracker/blob/master/README.md

```
   val settings = TrackerSettings()
            .setUseNetwork(true)
            .setUseGPS(true)
            .setUsePassive(false)
            .setTimeBetweenUpdates(1000)
            .setMetersBetweenUpdates(10F)
```

And i change postions to get distance between to position using:

```
 val distance = currentPosition!!.distanceTo(location)
 totalDistance += distance
```

But the result is not precise, anyone how can give a better solution

Answer (score 0):

```
private fun distance(
    startLatitude: Double,
    startLongitude: Double,
    endLatitude: Double,
    endLongitude: Double,
    unit: String
): String {
    val theta = startLongitude - endLongitude
    var dist: Double = sin(deg2rad(startLatitude)) * sin(deg2rad(endLatitude)) +
            cos(deg2rad(startLatitude)) * cos(deg2rad(endLatitude)) * cos(deg2rad(theta))
    dist = acos(dist)
    dist = rad2deg(dist)
    dist *= 60 * 1.1515 //miles
    if (unit == "k") {
        dist *= 1.609344 // km
    }
    return dist.toString()
} 
private fun deg2rad(deg: Double): Double {
        return deg * 3.1415926535897932 / 180.0
    }


private fun rad2deg(rad: Double): Double {
        return rad * 180.0 / 3.1415926535897932
    }
```

Answer (score 0):

You can use android.location.Location.distanceBetween() method which does this quite well. [For more info](https://developer.android.com/reference/android/location/Location.html#distanceBetween(double,%20double,%20double,%20double,%20float[]))